# ¿Cómo puedo activar un link?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo dejar activado (`active`) un link (`<a>`) con JavaScript?

Mi código HTML

```
<div id="marco2">
    <a href="#" onclick="play1();"  class="myButton">A-1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="play2();" class="myButton2">A-2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="play3();" class="myButton3">A-3</a>
</div>
```

Css

```
.myButton:active,.myButton2:active,.myButton3:active {
    position:relative;
    top:-9px;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bbbbbb 5%, #bbbbbb 100%);
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
}
```

Comment: Puedes lanzar un evento *mousedown* con ese elemento como target... en teoría eso debería marcarlo como `:active` hasta que se encuentre el evento mouseup correspondiente. Pero... dudo que eso sea muy *estable* especialmente en diferentes navegadores. Por no hablar de que un click en otra parte te lo eliminaría. Lo que suele hacerse en estos casos es añadir una ***clase*** `.active`, eso si que es fácil de añadir y quitar con javascript, es compatible con todos los navegadores y no da problemas.

Comment: Gracias por responder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo no trabajar con pseudo-clases ya que la comunidad tiene otras prácticas. Lo estándar, es pintar la selección de un elemento con una clase CSS y controlarlo con Javascript.

Visita el enlace para que tengas otra visión de lo que te comento:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp

Comment: Gracias por responder! justamente estaba haciendo eso despues de divagar por las redes buscando informacion.

Comment: Genial! Este tipo de buenas prácticas te servirán de mucho cuando empieces a trabajar con React, Angular o Vue. W3Schools contiene muchos cursos básicos pero que te presentan buenas prácticas o convenciones, por favor, siempre usa las documentaciones de Mozilla o W3 como referencias para partir, una vez entendido el proceso, se libre de experimentar. Buena suerte en el viaje!